# Paste objects from PowerPoint into C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, powerpoint, clipboard

We are developing a .NET WPF application used to draw shapes, write text and paste images. We recently added the feature to paste images from the Windows clipboard using `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` and the `getImage()` method.

We need to implement a feature to paste objects from Microsoft PowerPoint. When selecting several objects in a PowerPoint page, and copying - PowerPoint generates a Image which contains all selected objects. We want to implement so that pasting from PowerPoint, we can read the list of objects from the clipboard and paste them in as individual objects. This should be possible, as PowerPoint stores the objects in several ways in the clipboard - it can be verified by copying a number of objects from PowerPoint and pasting into Word, the objects will be pasted separately. We want to do the same in our application.

When i copy a number of objects in powerpoint, then do `Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats();`i get a list of data formats stored in the clipboard. The list looks like the following:

- "Preferred DropEffect"
- "InShellDragLoop"
- "Object Descriptor"
- "PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Theme"
- "PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Color Scheme"
- "PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Shapes"
- "Art::GVML ClipFormat"
- "PNG"
- "JFIF"
- "GIF"
- "System.Drawing.Bitmap"
- "Bitmap"
- "EnhancedMetafile"
- "MetaFilePict"
- "Preferred DropEffect"

When i do `Clipboard.GetData(string format)` by using any of these formats, i get back a `System.IO.MemoryStream`. I don't know how to read it into an object, or a list of objects, or how i should approach that.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on "PowerPoint 12.0 Internal Shapes" or any of the other formats which look interesting, and do now know how to read them and parse them in our application code.

Has anyone managed to achieve pasting from an Office application in the "Office-way", i.e maintaining the individual objects? What is my best approach to try to read and parse the objects in the clipboard?

Kind regards,
Div

Comment: MemoryStream is basically just a byte array. For PNG/GIF/JFIF, that's fairly obvious; they're complete image files. For the others, honestly no clue, you'll have to research into that yourself.